# Javascript async/await return value is undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function that posts data via an API. I want to return the response...I am following tutorials online to try to understand async/await, and the way I have it laid out now seems to be correct to me.

I can print inside the postAsset.then statement, but the return value is always undefined. That's what I thought await fixed, unsure why it is still undefined in this case?

```
const postAsset = async (assetToPost) => {
    let token = await retrieveToken()

    if (token !== undefined && token !== 'Error') {
        const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        };

        let urlAssets = `${API_ROUTE}${ASSETS.ASSETS_API_URL}`

        axios
            .post(urlAssets, assetToPost, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                let assetId = response.data
                return assetId
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('POSTING ASSET ERROR: ', error.message);
                return -1
            })
    }
}

const postData = async () => {
        // post asset, get id response.
        // then post beacons in loop, get id response for each
        // then post a beaconId as part of assetId

        let assetId = await postAsset(asset)
        console.log(assetId)
}
```

Comment: Don't mix `async/await` with `.then()`. Use `let response = await axios(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using `.then` and not `await` - which would work if you'd return the promise that you get, but you don't.

**Solution 1:**

Return the promise you get from `axios.post` (add `return` in front of it):

```js
return axios
    .post(...)
    .then(...)
```

**Solution 2 (better):**

Don't mix `.then` with `async`/`await`, instead *only* use `async`/`await`:

```js
try {
  const response = await axios.post(urlAssets, assetToPost, config)
  return response.assetId
} catch (error) {
  console.log('POSTING ASSET ERROR:', error)
  return -1
}
```

(By the way, I changed `error.message` to just `error` so you won't lose the important stack information!)

Answer (score 1):

the function postAsset should return a promise, and within the promise should execute the call axios.post

Answer (score 1):

You're returning your `assetId` from the `axios` call but not returning anything from the `postAsset` method.
Just add the `return` keyword before you `axios` call. It will work.

```
    return axios
        .post(urlAssets, assetToPost, config)
        .then(function (response) {
            let assetId = response.data
            return assetId
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('POSTING ASSET ERROR: ', error.message);
            return -1
        })
```